# Access another installed Ubuntu terminal on the same machine

Tags: command-line, dual-boot

I recently installed two different versions of Ubuntu on two different hard disks in the same machine. I want to access the terminal of Ubuntu 2 when I have booted from Ubuntu 1. How do I do this?

I have mounted the hard disk on which Ubuntu 2 is installed. What I want to do is to run terminal commands of programs installed in Ubuntu 2 from Ubuntu 1.

Comment: This likely will not work if the program on Ubuntu 2 requires different shared library or kernel levels to Ubuntu 1.  That would be like taking a gearbox from one car and expecting to slot it into a different car.  If you want to run a script or some program which is independent of shared library and kernel differences that may work, but the paths of files on Ubuntu 2 mounted on Ubuntu 1 will be different to when you boot directly from Ubuntu 2.

Comment: Yes, I understand the case where it would not be possible to run a program if there were kernel differences. Could you tell me a way to run a program  from a terminal of Ubuntu 2 from Ubuntu 1, if such differences do not exist?
What I would also be interested in knowing is whether there is a way to access the terminal of Ubuntu 2 from Ubuntu 1 and make changes(like apt-get install), given that  I have knowledge of the username and password.

Comment: You may be able to use `chroot` for this.  Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot for more info.